# Is Batch Processing Of Paypal Reference Transactions Possible

Tags: paypal

I have a large number of monthly subscribers that I would like to bill using paypal reference transactions.

Does either paypal API (classic or rest) support submission of multiple reference transactions in a single request, or do I need to submit each reference transaction within its own request?

Answer (score 0):

Each reference transaction must be a separate request. It's also worth noting that (at least with Classic) you have to disable CVV2 checks (since you don't have it and neither does PayPal, per PCI compliance) or your call will fail.